# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer never fires action

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to detect continued dragging past the bottom of the screen. I tried using the UIPanGestureRecognizer, but it stops firing as soon as the finger reaches the edge of the screen, except at the top. Now I'm trying the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer, but although the gestureRecognizer delegate method shouldReceiveTouch fires, the designated selector for the gesture itself never fires. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This code is in viewDidLoad:

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *selectScreenEdgeDrag = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenEdgeSelect:)];
[selectScreenEdgeDrag setEdges:UIRectEdgeBottom];
selectScreenEdgeDrag.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:selectScreenEdgeDrag];
```

Delegate methods:

```
- (void)screenEdgeSelect:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"screenEdgeSelect");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceivePress:(UIPress *)press {
    NSLog(@"shouldReceivePress");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(nonnull UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"shouldReceiveTouch");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
  return NO;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It never fires because you set the `edges` property to `UIRectEdgeBottom` and it collides with the system control center. Whenever I'm trying to swipe from the bottom edge the control center is showing up. If you set `edges` to `UIRectEdgeLeft` or `UIRectEdgeRight` everything will work fine.

If you still need to use bottom-edge gesture here are the options you have (as far as I know):

- You can hide the status bar (`UIStatusBar`): in this case your code will work as expected. Having the status bar hidden, the control center will not showing up automatically. Instead the small arrow will be displayed at the bottom edge giving the users possibility to open the settings if they want to. But you should be careful 'cause according to the [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1):

> Think twice before permanently hiding the status bar.

- You can ask the users to disable the control center in the iOS settings. But, I guess, they will be annoyed they must do such hard work :(

Hope this info will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but neither hiding the status bar nor disabling the display of Control Center within apps made any difference.

Comment: That's strange. I tried your code in the brand new Master-Detail project and it works. It sounds like you have another gesture recognizer that blocks this one. As stated in the doc, `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` and `gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` methods don't guarantee to prevent or remove a failure requirement.

Comment: There are no other gesture recognizers as yet. In any case, however, hiding the status bar or telling the user to turn off Control Center in apps is not a workable solution. There must be another way to detect continued dragging past the bottom of the screen. Why would Control Center be the problem, come to think of it? It appears when the user drags up *from* the bottom. In my case, I'm dragging *to* the bottom of the screen.

Comment: 1) I'm just telling you the results I got from playing with the real project. When Control Center is enabled the bottom edge recognizer never fires. 2) In the case of `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, you are specifying the edge _from_ which the gesture should begin. For dragging _to_ the bottom this recognizer isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Stan, it is helpful to know that I have misunderstood the purpose of the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. So that leads to the question, what mechanism can detect drags to the bottom of the screen and not cease when the finger reaches there?

Comment: If you want to post your #2 above as the answer, I'll mark it as such, and perhaps submit another question on the other issue. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, mate, I don't know any better solution other than using the pain old `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. As for your second comment, you can mark that post as the answer and submit another question if you think it will be more convenient for you to handle this situation with recognizers. I have no requirements for this :)

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed by watching the state changes of a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer! Good luck in your further iOS development.